# How to show chart with data from html form on the same page using python and flask

Tags: python, html, forms, matplotlib, flask

I am learning and got stucked. I want to build a super simple web app that takes some data (2 values) and plot them in a pie chart.
So far its working (getting data from form, creat the plot and print it on .../plot.png) but I would like to show the chart on the same page as the form and I am just guessing.

I guess I need to somehow link the chart in a dynamic way to the /home html but i don´t know how to do that.
I saw a lot of similar questions but very most of them are using js, I would like to keep it simple and do it only using flask.

main.py:

```
from flask import request
import io
#import random
from flask import Response
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas
#from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

app = Flask(__name__)


# Pie chart, where the slices will be ordered and plotted counter-clockwise:
labels = 'Aprovechado', 'Vertido'

explode = (0, 0) 

@app.route('/plot.png')
def plot_png():
    fig = create_figure()
    output = io.BytesIO()
    FigureCanvas(fig).print_png(output)
    return Response(output.getvalue(), mimetype='image/png')

def create_figure():
    autoconsumo = request.args.get('autoconsumo')
    vertido = request.args['vertido']
    sizes = [autoconsumo, vertido]
    fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
    ax1.pie(sizes, explode=explode, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%',
            shadow=True, startangle=90)
    ax1.axis('equal')  # Equal aspect ratio ensures that pie is drawn as a circle.
    return fig #render_template("autoconsumo.html") #fig

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("home.html")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #plot_png()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Flask Tutorial</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1> My First Try Using Flask </h1>
     <form action="/plot.png">
                 Autoconsumo <input type='number' name='autoconsumo'><br>
                 Vertido <input type='number' name='vertido'><br>
                 <input type='submit' value='Continue'>
             </form>
    <p> Flask is Fun </p>
    <img src="/plot.png?autoconsumo="'autoconsumo'"&vertido="'vertido' alt="my plot"> #<= I think its about this line
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i am quite sure the answer ist already out there I just can't find it. So I am also happy if someone got a link for me.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this answer before I read the part where you said `without Javascript` but I'll just post this anyway.  Let me know if you really want an answer which just involves Flask.

A very simple approach would be to add some `id` attributes to your `form`, `input` and `img` tags:

```
<form id='plot'>
  Autoconsumo <input type='number' id='autoconsumo' /><br />
  Vertido <input type='number' id='vertido' /><br />
  <input type='submit' value='Continue' />
</form>

<img id='img' alt="my plot">
```

Then immediately after this, add some javascript to obtain these elements, then change the image source on form submit:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    const form = document.getElementById('plot');
    const autoconsumo = document.getElementById('autoconsumo');
    const vertido = document.getElementById('vertido');
    const img = document.getElementById('img');

    // Event listener which changes the image src attribute on form submit:

    document.addEventListener('submit', function(e){

      e.preventDefault();  // Stops submit button from moving to new page

      img.src = '/plot.png?autoconsumo=' + autoconsumo.value + '&vertido=' + vertido.value;

    });
</script>
</body>
```

Others may have more elegant solutions, but this works.

Comment: Thanks a lot
It works
Offtopic but can you recomend me a enviroment for such a project. i first tried pycharm cumunity but i wasn't even able to get the matplot library working so I swapped to spyder (3 thinking about uptading) calling main.py from anaconda promt. But I guess there might be a better option.

Comment: @Schn5 what operating system you running?

Comment: I am using windows10

Comment: @Schn5 personally I'm on macOS (though these tools are Windows compatible): I use [SublimeText3](https://www.sublimetext.com/3) as my text editor, `git` for source control, and keep my environments in [docker](https://www.docker.com/get-started).